# Iterate through associative array and make new array using values

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I am querying the values for my associative array and I need to change the way in which it looks and add values of '0' where values have not been returned (based on count of $result)

i.e. `<=count($result)` there are 4 rooms, but only rooms 1 & 3 are returned, but I still need `r_id` values 2 & 4 with a `r_rate` value of 0.

**Currently my array looks like this:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [r_id] => 1
            [r_rate] => 180.00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [r_id] => 3
            [r_rate] => 100.00
        )

)
```

I want the array to look like this but I cannot define the arrays to merge as the `r_id` value will vary:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 180.00 // [r_id] => [r_rate]
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 100.00
    [4] => 0
)
```

I need the value of `r_id` to be the key, the value of `r_rate` to be the value, and to add the missing `r_id` values (2 & 4) with a value of 0.

**SQL:**

```
$sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT booking_room.r_id, room.r_rate FROM booking_room, room 
                    WHERE booking_room.b_id = '$b_id'
                    AND booking_room.r_id = room.r_id
                    ");
$sql->execute();
$result = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

**SQL Returns:**

```
r_id | r_rate
1    | 180.00
3    | 100.00
```

**I have tried so far:**

```
foreach ($result as $v) {
    foreach($v as $r) {
        $r_id[] = $r;
    }
}

$r_id = array_flip($r_id);

foreach ($r_id as $k => $v) {
    $r_id[$k] = $k;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to rearrange your arrays using PHP? Please post your code.

Comment: I have tried a lot of things, array flipping was the closest I got, but basically does not give me the `r_rate` or missing keys :( So stuck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick.

This will loop through the `$result` array looking for numerical keys starting at 1, ending where ever you want, 4 in the example.  If the key exists, we'll leave it alone, if it does not exist, we'll create it and set it to 0.

We'll run `ksort` at the end to sort the array items by the array key.

```
for ($r = 1; $r <= 4; $i++)
{
    if (!array_key_exists($r, $result))
    {
        $result[$r] = 0;
    }
}

ksort($result);
```